# How to format a jinja2 date of type String

Tags: python, html, date, yaml, jinja2

I receive a Json in my yml file and then it goes to my jinja2 html file.
I can use my data whithout modification but when I try filters or whatever to format my date it's failed.

Like this it's work whithout formating the date:

```
<p>{{rule.occurences[0]}}</p>
```

result :

```
2021-01-28T09:40:10.970Z
```

I want it to be like this:

```
2021-01-28
```

I tried this to format my date :

```
<p>{{rule.occurences[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}}</p>
```

result :

```
ERROR     -- [TaskProcess] 'str object' has no attribute 'strftime'
```

I also tried a custom filter:

```
<p>{{rule.occurences[0]|datetimeformat('%d-%m-%Y')}}</p>
```

result :

```
ERROR     -- [TaskProcess] datetimeformat() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

And also tried this one :

```
<p>{{rule.occurences[0]|iso8601_to_time|datetimeformat('%d-%m-%Y')}}</p>
```

result :

```
ERROR     -- [load_file] Couldn't load file jinja2: no filter named 'iso8601_to_time'
```

Any idea to solve this please ?

Answer (score 2):

```
import datetime
a='2021-01-28T09:40:10.970'
datetime.datetime.strptime(a[:10],'%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Output:

```
'2021-01-28'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I finally made it by doing this :
```{{rule.occurences[0]|truncate(10, True, '', 0)}}```